# Как читать текстовые файлы из assets, используя только нативный код?

Tags: android, c++, файлы, android-ndk, android-assets

Возникла проблема, когда я решил портировать свою с++ игру на андроид. Шрифты, текстуры читались нормально(средствами sdl2), а текстовые файлы не читались из assets с помощью fstream. Мой текущий код чтения текстового файла:

```
void load_strings(){
    string path="data/locales/ru/strings.txt";
    ifstream file(path.c_str());
    for(int q=0;q<STRINGS_COUNT;q++){
        getline(file,strings[q]);
        if(strings[q][strings[q].size()-1]=='\r')strings[q].pop_back();
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Я использую только нативный код, без использования Java.

Comment: вижу вы используете относительный путь - вы уверены, что он верный?

Comment: *"Я использую только нативный код, без использования Java."* - на самом деле нет.

Comment: стесняюсь спросить, а к чему эти сложности?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, он верный, по этому пути файлик лежит

Comment: @DrMcSheen, в этом файлике хранятся строки для меню игры

Comment: @Nikita_yfh я просто уточню: вы вкурсе, что относительные пути считаются от директории запуска исполняемого файла? Вы уверены что бинарник запускается именно из необходимой вам директории?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, да
Но почему же тогда текстуры и шрифты грузились нормально?
`textures = load("data/textures/a.png");`

Comment: @Nikita_yfh если для текстур вы тоже указывали относительные пути и они загружаются, тогда они действительно верные. В таком случае советую (да и для любого другого случая) добавить проверку на открытие вашего файла. По коду ошибки в fstream обычно можно понять в чем проблема

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а как его узнать?

Comment: sdl получает пути через java API, вам придется делать также

Comment: @Nikita_yfh если этого не знаете - открывайте документацию, там все расписано

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а можно разархивировать текстовые файлы и кинуть их в /sdcard/Android/data/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxx ?

Comment: @Nikita_yfh не могу ответить, так как не понимаю в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось читать assets, используя средства SDL2 (SDL_RWops)